# What does the core count 4(+4 core Driver core) means in ADF dataflow, does it mean 2 node with 4 core in each for master and worker

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrZM9.png)

- Also, there are other feature options like 32(+ 16 Driver cores). Is this also mean the same 2 nodes i.e 16 core for the driver and 32 core for the worker?
- And also what about the memory configuration allocated?
- If only one bulky worker with 32 cores is used instead of 4 workers with 8 cores in each, Can't I can call it horizontal scaling which is against the concept of spark distributed processing?

Answer (score 0):

4+4 cores = 4 cores for the driver node and 4 cores for the worker node.

When you apply larger core configurations (i.e. 32+16), ADF can change the implementation in terms of the number of VMs to give you the 32 that you requested. Because the Spark environment is abstracted and serverless, it is not something that is exposed and is an implementation detail.